# VBA:Compare string with find function value

Tags: vbscript

How to compare with case sensitive in find function?

Like 
  stringtxt = Range("A1:A10").Find(What:=stringtxt , Lookat:=xlWhole,MatchCase:=False)

Here suppose stringtxt="ABCD (abcd)"
AND in range one of the cells may have value like "ABCD (ABCD)"
I have to compare this with contents in range specified.
I tried adding like "UCase".Didn`t work.MatchCase i tried with both true and false values.Didnt work though.
Suggest me some better answers to compare.

Comment: What do you mean with didnt work? Does it pops an error? or finds no value? Please post the procedure code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

One of the parameters to the Find method is a MatchCase parameter, as follows:

[image]

Think that should help you solve this problem.

Comment: :I tried adding MatchCase:= both true/false,it didnt work.suggest me some answers plz.